# Variable not defined in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to display the for loop result (i<10) but the message I get is that "vehicles" not defined. I've declared a variable as empty array and then used push to enter the results of the for loop. Any suggestions?

```
class VehicleList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    let vehicles = []
  }

    vehicles(){
      for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        vehicles.push({
          manufacturer: faker.vehicle.manufacturer(),
          model: faker.vehicle.model(),
          type: faker.vehicle.type(),
          fuel: faker.vehicle.fuel(),
          vin: faker.vehicle.vin(),
          color: faker.vehicle.color()
        })
      }
      return <div>{vehicles}</div>
    }

  generateVehicle(){
    let manufacturer = faker.vehicle.manufacturer()
    return{
      manufacturerN : manufacturer
    }
  }

   render(){
   return (
    <div style={{ display: 'block', width: 400, padding: 30 }}>
        <ListGroup>
          <div>{vehicles}</div>
        </ListGroup>

   </div>
  );
}
}

export default VehicleList
```

Comment: In javascript let and const get block scope. So your `let vehicles` won't be available outside the constructor scope. In react, you are trying to mutate an object trying to display something with it. React works based on props and state. You are using none. You may read about those and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! I will read the documentation again, it is a little confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see multiple issues in your code. But all fixable!

First off, use the `this` keyword to instantiate the `vehicles` instance in the constructor, so you can access it throughout the component.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.vehicles = [];
}
```

Next, in your `vehicles()` method, reference the **vehicles** array using `this` keyword.

```
vehicles() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      this.vehicles.push({
        // add vechiles 
      });
    }
  }
```

Returning `<div>{vehicles}</div>` might not be appropriate, since `vehicles` is an array. You should iterate through its elements instead to add them to DOM.

But you might not need to return anything here since you can access `vehicles` directly in `render()` (as shown below).

We first update vehicles by calling the `vehicles()` method and then iterate through each vehicle to add it to the DOM.

```
render() {
    // update vechiles
    this.vehicles();
    // render vehciles
    return (
      <div style={{ display: "block", width: 400, padding: 30 }}>
        <ListGroup>
          {this.vehicles.map((vehicle) => (
            <div>{vehicle}</div>
          ))}
        </ListGroup>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

If you'd like this to be re-rendered anytime vehicles change, you can store the vehicles in the state.

Lastly, in your code you're referencing `faker`. If it is something stored in your `props`, don't forget to extract it from props first (constructor could be a good place for it), or reference it everywhere with the props keyword (`props.faker` or `props.faker[0]` if it's an array).

Comment: Thank you so much for your explained answer!! I am learning how to code, I understand most of the topics but react has giving me a hard time. I'm confused to be honest, I added what you told me and now the page isn't rendering anything :(

Comment: What I had before was:

      manufacturer: faker.vehicle.manufacturer(),
      model: faker.vehicle.model(),
      type: faker.vehicle.type(),
      fuel: faker.vehicle.fuel(),
      vin: faker.vehicle.vin(),
      color: faker.vehicle.color()
    };
  render(){
   return (
    <div style={{ display: 'block', width: 400, padding: 30 }}>
      <h1>My {this.state.brand}</h1>
      <p>it is a {this.state.color}</p>
      <p>from {this.state.year}</p>
      <button
      type = 'button'
      onClick={this.changeColor}
      >shuffle</button>

Comment: In this assignment, I do not know what I'm doing but I will keep trying. Thank you everyone.

Comment: No worries. It can be confusing for sure. But if you still find it hard, I recommend you watch some tutorials on YouTube where they build some sort of react project from scratch. 
Reading the documentation can be confusing at times. Seeing how these concepts are actually implemented helps to understand them better.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I will definitely watch some tutorials to try to understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you two potential solutions:

First, try adding `this` to the front of the vehicles call. Ergo it will look like `this.vehicle.append()`. You may also need to add `this` to the front of the declaration ergo `let this.vehicle = []`.

If that doesn't solve the issue try using a react state instead.
`this.state = {vehicles: []};`
and then call it with
`{this.state.vehicle.append()}`
see https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_state.asp

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I used the second approach.